# Access function in property dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a SPA with VueJS and I need to validate multiple forms in different steps.

This are the observers:

```
<ValidationObserver ref="registrationformstep1">
...
</ValidationObserver>

<ValidationObserver ref="registrationformstep2">
...
</ValidationObserver>

<ValidationObserver ref="registrationformstep3">
...
</ValidationObserver>
```

Now I'd like to validate the current form using

```
 async nextStep () {
   const result = await this.$refs.registrationformstep1.validate ();

   if (result) {
     this.step = this.step + 1;
   }
}
```

So my question is: How can I call `refs.registrationformstepX` dynamically? Basically I'd like to insert `this.step` there.

What I tried:

```
let observer = `registrationformstep${this.step}.validate`;
const result = await this[observer]()
```

This did not work with the following error:

> this[observer] is not a function

Comment: did you try `const result = await this.$refs[\`registrationformstep${this.step}\`].validate ();`?